# upload file from php dreamviewer to remote server

Tags: php

**I am new in php.I am Uploading a file from local to remote server but file is not uploading .I am uploading pdf file from server php which is in Dreamweaver but file is not uploaded what to do..And next thing i dont want extension .pdf i wants only name of pdf.. ?**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                            echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 

                            $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                            $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                            $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                            $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"]; 

                        if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                        {
                                if($fileSize<=200)
                            { 
                                $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                $newFileName=$random.$fileName;
                                $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;


if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                            {
                                echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                            }

                        }
                        else
                            {
                                    return false;
                                    echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                            } 







<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="myform" >
                <br/>

                <label>Select Category:</label>      
                <div class="form-group">
                  <?php

                        include('config.php');
                        $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from category");
                        ?>


<select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
                        <?php
                         echo"<option>---Select---</option>";
                        while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                        {

                            $selectedCat = '';
                            if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                            {
                                $selectedCat = "selected";
                            }



echo "<option value='$query[catnm]' $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>";


                        }

                    ?>                                    
                    </select>
<br/>
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product  
   Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php if(isset($query4['prodnm'])){
   echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>  "/>
           </div>

         <div class="form-group">       

  <textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" name="prod_dtl"   
  placeholder="Product Detail" "rows="10" cols="62" required><?php 
  if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?></textarea>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>

<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept="application/pdf" 
name="filepdf" >


        file : <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
        echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input id="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="updates" 


<?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo    

"checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
            ?> />Is Downloadable <br />

        </label>
        </div>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Upload" name="date" value="<?php    
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = $_GET['id'];echo $query4['date'];

    }
    else
    {
    echodate('d/m/Y');
    }? >"id="datepicker-7">
         <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" 
onclick="madeSelection(document.getElementById('catnm'),'Please Select` 
Category',event)" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = 
$_GET['id'];echo"Update";}else{echo"Submit";}?>"/>
<input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.location='index.php'"/>
```

Comment: My admin panel is in Dreamweaver from where i am uploading file..

Comment: Please post your HTML code.